# Nuget seems to install the wrong version of System.Collections.Immutable

Tags: c#, nuget, immutable-collections

I have a confusing issue with Nuget. I have a number of projects who claim to have System.Collections.Immutable installed at version **1.3.0** but if I look at the version of the dll in all the references I see version **1.2.1.0**

When I open up the DLL with JustDecompile I see
[image]
which declares that the DLL version is indeed **1.2.1.0** but has been installed in directory **packages\System.Collections.Immutable.1.3.0**

A typical packages.config file will contain

```
<package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

and the csproj is

```
<Reference 
  Include="System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
     <HintPath>$(SolutionDir)packages\System.Collections.Immutable.1.3.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81\System.Collections.Immutable.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

If I try to open the downloaded nuget package from the gallery and open with nuget package explorer I get

[image]

Comment: I started facing this issue when I added `OrderBy` on list of anonymous types,  however installing `System.Collections.Immutable` package from nuget resolved the error.

Answer (score 3):

The NuGet package version and the assembly version are not necessarily the same. There is no restriction on what versions are used in either.

So looking at System.Collections.Immutable 1.3.0 the assembly version is 1.2.1.0 for the assemblies in the NuGet package.

If you cannot open the NuGet package in the NuGet Package Explorer you can open it in a zip file application such as 7-zip. Or just rename the file to .zip and open it with the built-in Windows zip file extractor.

Comment: The previous version of the library and nuget package were both 1.2.0 and then the library got promotoed to 1.2.1 and the nuget package to 1.3.0. I agree that in theory they don't need to match up but this smells. A random sampling of previous nuget versions of the same package have the assembly version and the nuget version matching.

Comment: I added an issue at corefx asking for an explanation. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14640

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem recently. `System.Collections.Immutable` is a multi-target package, so the version of the assembly imported to your solution depends on the target. For instance, if you are in a .Net Framework project, this is the file stored in `portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81` that will be used, hence the different version.